# Allow disabled button to trigger onClick event

Tags: reactjs

```
<button disabled={this.state.passingValidtions} type='submit'>Save</button>
```

When the above `button` is disabled I want the `onClick` to fire, so I can show a message to the user why the form isn't submittable.

But a disabled `button` disables `onClick` as well.

Is there any workaround here so I can put the `button` in disabled mode and still trigger `onClick`?

Comment: Add css to make the button look like disabled, but not actually disable it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a button look like disabled with `styles`. If you set the disabled attribute to true, it won't trigger `onClick` because it's not actually listening to it.

You should try something like that:

```
//disabled button
<button
  style={this.state.passingValidtions ? {
    ...
    opacity: "0.65",
    cursor: "not-allowed"
  } : { ... }} // style can be whatever you want for disabled buttons, it's just an example
  type="submit"
>
  Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fix that you can try is, put the disabled button inside a div. Then listen this div when click on it. And put the logic inside the listener function that only when you want to get the message(whatever) by clicking on it.

```
 const showMessage = (event)=> {
    if(condition){
        alert('The button is disabled ')
    }
}

<div onClick = {showMessage}>
    <button disabled} >
        click me
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to make use of “**aria-disabled**” instead of the **disabled** attribute. Add `aria-disabled="true"` to the `<button>` element.

```js
function handelOnClick(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // For ignoring form submit
  console.log("Disabled Button Clicked")
}
```

```html
<button type="button" title="disabled" aria-disabled="true" tabIndex="-1" onclick='handelOnClick(event)'>Disabled Button</button>
```